# Decrease Count of Apache2 Processes

Tags: linux

I found out there are seven (x7) **`apache2`** processes :

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND

  770 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  773 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  774 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  775 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  776 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  777 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1223 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I checked `apache2.conf` for *StartServers* and *MaxClients* but it was not there so I tried to lower it to 3 processes with editing the following file and setting the value of 3 to *StartServers* parameter and keeping the value of 5 for *MaxClients* parameter as shown below :

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

...
StartServers 3
MaxClients 5
...
```

But there are still and always 7 processes.
Any idea how to lower it to only 3 processes?

Comment: Which distribution are you on?

Comment: armbian headless

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.4 is highly configurable in terms of its worker processes.
You should read about the basic concepts of Apaches Multi-Processing Modules:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mpm.html

And for tuning the parameters you have to read the documentation where everyone is explaind in detail:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/worker.html

For limiting the total amount of processes you probably can use the **ServerLimit Directive**:

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_.conf*:

```
ServerLimit 3
StartServers 3
MinSpareServers 3
MaxConnectionsPerChild 250
```

Keep in mind that forcing the number of workers down can cause unexpected behaviour or slow down the application.

For example if your run a PHP Webfrontend with this settings the Apache can handle only 3 Request at a time. So you should think about what effect you want to achive and if it is really nessesary to limit the amount of processes.

Of course there will be always one parent process with **n** worker childprocesses:

```
root     15873  0.0  0.1  73636  2728 ?        Ss   17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15876  0.0  0.1 418104  2476 ?        Sl   17:25   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15877  0.0  0.1 418104  2480 ?        Sl   17:25   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15878  0.0  0.1 418104  2484 ?        Sl   17:25   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: thanks, any how to example please? I just installed sudo apt-get install apache2 but then I found out, that I need to keep RAM usage for apache process as low as possible (embedded board with just 256MB ram, but only 1 or 2 users will browse simple php scripts at once). Many thanks